# How can I bulk delete by a List of model classes with JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Normally deleting many records from a table at once when you have a List is pretty straightforward. Right now my query looks like this:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("DELETE from SomeEntity e WHERE e.id in :someEntityIds")
            .setParameter("someEntityIds", someEntityIds);
```

where `someEntityIds` is a `List<int>` of id's that I want to delete.

However, I need to modify the code to delete based on two different id's. I have a model class, `SomeModel` that has two variables in it

```
public class SomeModel {

    public String someId;

    public Long anotherId;

}
```

Note that this model does not directly correspond with my JPA model/entity. The table will have these two values, plus a bunch more.

I have a list, `List<SomeModel>`, that I need to use to delete multiple records at once. In other words, I have to delete every single record that matches both `someId` and `anotherId` in a list of `SomeModels`. Is this possible without iterating through the List and running a delete query on each item in the list?

Comment: It would help your question (and you) to try to write the raw SQL query for the delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly `concat` could work but you'll have to prepare a list of composite ids beforehand:

```
// List<SomeModel> list = ... // assuming there's a list of some models
List<String> compositeIds = list.stream()
                                .map(m -> m.someId + "#" + Integer.toString(m.anotherId))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

Query q = em.createQuery("DELETE from SomeModel e WHERE concat(e.someId, '#', e.anotherId) in :compositeIds")
            .setParameter("compositeIds ", compositeIds);
```